# Handling many connection by Python

Tags: c++, python, sockets, tcp

I've a client/server application. Client App will be coded on C++. On Linux we have server program. This server will handle **thousands of users** and **millions of requests** and those thousands of users will be 24/7 connected to the server and many of the data will be written to the memory (not all but required)

First of all, i looked `Real Studio`. They offer Linux targetted builds. It's language is basic. I also discover `Python 3` which is very stable and friendly.

Also discover that Python has `server_forever()` method and also if it gives an error during connection, Python won't close the process, instead, it is continued to accept next connections. Which is very flexible.

But as i mentioned before, i will handle thousands of users at the same time and millions of requests. Such as this application, should I trust Python? Can python handle such this requests?

You may assume that program coded very-well and take care of handler.

Should i use RealStudio for machine code or even C++?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877643/handle-multiple-socket-connections) but it has a different direction.

For me, using Python, Real Studio or C++ isn't a problem. But i liked Python. I just not sure if i should go with `scripted` python language or using direct machine code.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: The choice of language is mostly irrelevant to this question as the operating system will be maxed out before your server code ever runs. If you really mean "thousands of users" *simultaneously*, you'll need a server cluster and data-center operations, etc.

Comment: Indeed. Let's say i have. Eventually, I have to code server program at that point. In this case, should i rely on Python Script or C++/Real Studio Machine Code. I really need to know how Python acts on such this environment. When I code the server stuff, I have no chance to cancel and switch to other language.

Comment: You say "millions of requests", but in what sort of time period? A million requests per day could easily be handled by a single PC, but a million requests per second would likely require a bit more hardware. As for choice of language, it doesn't really matter too much - just pick whatever you're most comfortable with.

Comment: @Aya, No, Not short of time period. Let' s say server lived 10 days. In this whole 10 days millions of requests will be made. But server never down. It will be alive and requests will be handled. So, I assume that you are saying Python 3 -no matter of script or machine code- can handle such this requests?.

Comment: Well, if you like Python, then give it a go. It's a good language for prototyping, so build a small prototype and run some stress tests to see how well it copes.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to connect many times and assignee variables in memory. Let' s see what develops. You may give it as an answer in proper way so i can accept :)

Comment: @Aya, Just wanted to let you know that, i created stress test that opens, writes and assigne variable at memory of 1.000.000 connection one by one without delay between connections. Works like a charm. Python in the end of the day is machine code too. So, issue resolved :)

Comment: @user2398497 Added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your elaborations in the comments, you should be okay with Python, and since it sounds as if Python is your preferred option, then I'd go with that.

Python is a good language for prototyping, since its terse syntax, native container types, and fairly comprehensive built-in library lets you put together reasonably complex programs in a very small amount of time compared to many other languages.

There's no substitute for practical testing though, so I'd recommend building a small prototype of your server and stress-test it to see how well it copes with the sort of loads you're expecting in production.